# Relation does not exist: raw sql query django --- I have got the table name right: app name _ model name : it has to be something else

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

Hi I am running a raw sql query in Django,

I keep getting relation "makeprofile_compositemodel" does not exist

The models name is compositeModel and the app is makeprofile, when looking at the db in postgres the name of the table is correct and copy & pasted as such. I just don't know what I am doing wrong or why this error is occurring.... If anyone has as any suggestions please let me know.

```
con =None

def LocData (LocList):

    if len(LocList) == 1:

        try:

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("""SELECT US.*

                    FROM        makeProfile_compositemodel US, makeProfile_profile UP

                    WHERE       US.profile_id = UP.user_id AND
                                UP.country = %s




                        """,[LocList[0]])


            while True:


                rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000000)

                if not rows:
                      break
                print("+++++++++",len(rows))

                DictReturn.update(TheOtherGuy(rows))


        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:

            print ('Error' ,e)
            sys.exit(1)


        finally:

            if cursor:
                cursor.close()

    else:
        return None
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "makeprofile_compositemodel" does not exist
LINE 3:                     FROM        makeProfile_compositemodel U...
                                        ^
Exception Location: /home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/

  utils.py in execute, line 64
```

TRACEBACK

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/linkMatchs/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'registration',
 'newsletter',
 'questions',
 'makeProfile',
 'linkMatchs',
 'home')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/src/linkMatchs/views.py" in index
  43.         query_set = lookUp(a=None, **kwargs)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/src/linkMatchs/search.py" in lookUp
  249.     LocData(LocList)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/src/linkMatchs/search.py" in LocData
  137.                         """,[LocList[0]])
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/g4/django/ruPure/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /linkMatchs/
Exception Value: relation "makeprofile_compositemodel" does not exist
LINE 3:                     FROM        makeProfile_compositemodel U...
                                        ^
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK so wierd, but because the app was named :makeProfile and therefore the table name was :makeProfile_compositemodel it couldnt find it....

SO: the solution was to make the app name letters all lower cases which resulted in a table  makeprofile_compositemodel..... This solved this for me...
OR: You can just place makeProfile_compositemodel in "" that should work to
PS dont forget to do a new migration as there will be a new table....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

`>>>obj=Model.objects.raw("""SELECT "colName"  FROM table where "colname"= 'value(if it is a string)'  """)`

`>>> for o in obj:`

`...     print(o)`